# Implement multi tenancy in a stateless environment using Spring and Hibernate and Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, multi-tenant

I’m trying to understand how we build a RESTful API for a SaaS product where it involves multi tenancy.  The technology stack is Java using Spring and Hibernate and deploying a WAR to Tomcat.

My main issue is how do we maintain the tenant_id within the REST call in order for the application to use the correct database connection when performing CRUD.  Seeing that Tomcat uses a thread pool and reuses threads we should not use ThreadLocal.

I have read that slf4j supports this with the MDC implementation for logging.  A servelet filter does maintain the tenant_id upfront and clears it upon exit of the filter.  Therefore, the logger uses the correct tenant_id in the messages.

At the same time using a ThreadLocal goes against the principle of stateless as this implicitly adds a state.

Furthermore, the idea of creating some kind of ContextSession object holding the tenant_id and passing it around does not seem to solve my issue. As this object would be passed down the layers of the DAL and DAO to load the objects.  I want to avoid this high coupling on this ContextSession class, as well having to include it on many method signatures.

How do I implement multi tenancy in a stateless environment?

Comment: Did you solve the issue (without using HttpSession ? ) I have the same issue, where I need to select the database based on user.

Comment: The way I did it was to use ThreadLocal with the Tomcat thread that is used.  In my case the URL (eventually headers) contains the id.  Since each user request will use a unique thread the ThreadLocal will store this id.  If you're not using Tomcat you need a way to extract the id and ensure you have 1 thread per call.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs onto your application, they would be somehow associated with a tenant.  So the tenant information should be accessible from the spring SecurityContext.

As an example, if i have an application with 2 tenants; tenantA and tenantB.  When logging on, the user needs to indicate somehow which tenant they belong to.  This can be done in various ways, such as using different host names (eg. tenantA.myapp.com, tenantB.myapp.com) or url parameters, or entering the tenant information on a logon form.  When authenticating the user, you then need to use the authentication realm associated with the particular tenant.  As part of the authentication, the spring SecurityContext should be setup to contain information that lets you determine which tenant the user belongs to on subsequent service calls from the user.  The SecurityContext should be accessible from different service layers of your application without you needing to explicitly program anything for that to happen.

Comment: Thanks. So in the DAO how would I inject the SecurityContex for the user's tenant_id? I assume its scope would be session?

Comment: Look at http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security for ideas on how to access the SecurityContext

Comment: Also, the SecurityContext doesn't necessarily have to be session scoped.  If you use something like oauth2 with stateless sessions, the token used in the request will be stored in the securitycontext and contain realm information (which will tell you the tenant).

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to associate your current `HttpSession` to a specific tenant.

1. Provide some type of `client_id` parameter on the URL that is used to reverse lookup the specified backend `tenant` through a centralize common client database.
2. Associate an authenticated user to a specific `tenant`.  When users authenticate against a centralized user database, the tenant is looked up based on the user account.

How that `tenant_id` is passed to the lower application tiers is really a matter of taste.

My first option would be to use a `ThreadLocal`.  If you're already using Spring Security, you're already using `ThreadLocal` variables and may not even be aware of it.

The use of `ThreadLocal` variables do not break the stateless design of your application.  You just have pieces of code that expect a variable to contain a specific value that it must use.  It's just a fancy way to pass state across your application tiers without actually explicitly passing it as arguments on a method signature.

Obviously the other two options are to use some *Context* object or merely pass the value directly downstream.

In a web application, I would typically do this via some interceptor or filter that would per request lookup the request parameter `client_id` and get the associated `tenantId` and set that in a special `ThreadLocal` variable.

Once the call to `chain.doFilter( request, response );` has returned or throws an exception, you simply then clear the `ThreadLocal` variable.